# Save value of select after sending page via php with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Good evening guys, I have a question and I'm looking for someone to help me.

I have the following problem, I generate a `select` with all the options coming from a database and I send the information via a post action, using php.

I am wanting that when returning to the page, with the select option, after The last selected value is active to the form. Is it possible to do this via javascript or something?

*Sorry for bad English

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM curso WHERE data  = '$date'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conexao2);

    echo "<select name=\"curso\" >";

    while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $nome_evento = $linha[1];
        $cod_evento = $linha[0];
        echo  "<option  value=".$cod_evento.">".$nome_evento."</option>"."<br>" ;
    } 
    echo  "</select>";
```

Comment: Hello by the way. Are you triying to set the select box to the previous selected item. <option value="VALUE"  selected>VALUE</option>

Comment: What you need to do is get that selected value as well and pass it in as a variable then you can do a php if check during the loop to then set the `selected` value to the one that matches the currently seelcted one, see my explination below

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, you need to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Enstage - I know this is obsolete, thank you for pointing out. I need to learn PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you will need to also get the value that was entered previously as well.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM curso WHERE data  = '$date'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql, $conexao2);

 $currentlySelectedValue = ///Add your code here to get this value

 echo "<select name=\"curso\" >";

 while($linha = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $nome_evento = $linha[1];
    $cod_evento = $linha[0];
    echo  '<option value=' . $cod_evento . ' ' . (($cod_evento === $currentlySelectedValue) ? 'selected' : '') . '>' . $nome_evento . '</option>';
 }
 echo  "</select>";
```

So what the is happening in the `option` area is:

`(($cod_evento === $currentlySelectedValue) ? 'selected' : '')`

that is checking the selected value with the values you're outputting, and if one matches, it will then add the `selected` value to it.

Hope this helps in anyway.

Comment: I'm going to test now.Thank you very much.

Comment: i'm not going to be around for a few hours at its late here, but hopefully you have a start and if its near others can help, thanks

Comment: Thank you, worked properly, thanks for your time lost kkk.

Comment: brilliant, just mark it as th e correct answer, and glad to help.

Comment: PS: as @Enstage mentioned please look up PDO.  DO NOT USE the outdate and insecure `mysql_query`  http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp Its more secure and up to date

Answer (score 0):

**@Anderson Augusto Is it possible to do this via javascript or something?**

Yes you can approach it via Ajax without reloading the page

1) create **ajax.php** Inside that  you have this

```
<?php 
class Curso {

    // Print select option value as soon as page load
       public function curso($date){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM curso WHERE data  = '$date'";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql, $conexao2);
     while($linha = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $nome_evento = $linha[1];
        $cod_evento = $linha[0];
        return ("<option  value=".$cod_evento.">".$nome_evento."</option>");
    } 


         }
}

?>
```

2) create **frontpage.php** Inside that you have this

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My front page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form id="CursoForm">
    <?php 
    require("ajax.php");
    $OptionValues= new Curso();
    $TheValues =$OptionValues->curso("YOUR-DATE");
    ?>  
    <!--Maybe some other inputs-->
    <input type="text">
    <select name="curso"><?php echo($TheValues);?></select>
    </form>

    <script>
//==================================
$("form#CursoForm").on("submit",function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "path/to/your/further/function.php",
cache: false,   
dataType: 'html',//choose what you are expecting e.g. JSON | HTML | TEXT
data: $(this).serialize(),
success: function(data){      
//handle do something with re
},
error: function(){      
 //handle do something wth the error 
}
});
});
//  
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, but I have solved the problem, thank you very much.